# Print specific lines that have two or more occurrences of a particular character

Tags: sed

I have file with some text lines. I need to print lines 3-7 and 11 if it has two "b". I did

`sed -n '/b\{2,\}/p' file`  but it printed lines where "b" occurs two times in a row

Comment: Did you mean `sed -n '/b[^b]*b/p`? Or `sed -n '/b.*b/p`? Do you need to check the line number as well or not?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I need chek the line number but I did't use that in my example

Comment: Maybe `sed -n '3,7{/b[^b]*b/p};11{/b[^b]*b/p}' file` will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -n '3,7{/b[^b]*b/p};11{/b[^b]*b/p}' file
## that is equal to 
sed -n '3,7{/b[^b]*b/p};11{//p}' file
```

Note that `b[^b]*b` matches `b`, then any zero or more chars other than `b` and then a `b`. The `//p` in the second part matches the most recent pattern , i.e. it matches the same  `b[^b]*b` regex.

Note you might also use `b.*b` regex if you want, but the bracket expressions tend to word faster.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/rLDdJO), tested with `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`:

```sh
s='11bb1
b222b
b  n    b
ww
ee
bb
rrr
fff
999
10
11 b nnnn bb
www12'
sed -ne '3,7{/b[^b]*b/p};11{/b[^b]*b/p}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
b  n    b
bb
11 b nnnn bb
```

Only lines 3, 6 and 11 are returned.

Comment: Since it doesn't seem to be "exactly 2 `b`" and there is no anchoring, I think it doesn't matter what's between the `b`s: `b.*b` would return the same results as `b[^b]*b`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, but the bracket expression one should work faster.

Comment: Suggestion: use `11{//p}` to avoid repeating the regex

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk for simplicity, clarity, portability, maintainability, etc. Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '( (3<=NR && NR<=7) || (NR==11) ) && ( gsub(/b/,"&") >= 2 )' file
```

Notice how if you need to change a range, add a range, add other line numbers, change how many `b`s there are, add other chars and/or strings to match, add some completely different condition, etc. it's all absolutely clear and trivial.

For example, want to print the line if there's exactly either 13 or 27 `b`s instead of `2 or more`:?

```
awk '( (3<=NR && NR<=7) || (NR==11) ) && ( gsub(/b/,"&") ~ /^(13|27)$/ )' file
```

Want to print the line if the line number is between 23 and 59 but isn't 34?

```
awk '( 23<=NR && NR<=59 && NR!=34 ) && ( gsub(/b/,"&") >= 2 )' file
```

Try making similar changes to a sed script. I'm not saying you can't force it to happen, but it's not nearly as trivial, clear, portable, etc. as it is using awk.

Comment: Well, yeah, that gsub's great if you feel like typing sed/awk gibberish (`&`) that you don't need.  There's no function to only count the matches w/o the substitution?

Comment: @stevesliva There is no tool named sed/awk, nor awk/perl, etc., the script in my answer is awk, that's all. The `&` is a well-known construct used in many tools/languages to mean "the matching string". The awk language is tiny and simple to use/read because it's built on the premise that you shouldn't create constructs to do things that are easy to do with other constructs. Given that premise and `gsub(/foo/,"&")` tells you how many occurrences of `foo` exist (and can be used for more than that) there's simply no need for some other specialized construct to just tell you that same information.

Comment: What I meant is, there’s really not a *one* parameter function that will return the count of matches?   It would help clarity to not have the second hieroglyph parameter.  Sounds like the answer is no, and that’s fine.

Comment: Right, there is no need for such a function because it's trivial to do what you want with other existing constructs and so such a function doesn't exist per the awk language mantra of only providing constructs to do things that are hard to do with existing constructs. There's a million things it'd be nice if there was a specific construct to do at the time when you need that functionality (I'd love a way to set FS and OFS in a single instruction - oh well) but then you end up with language bloat and unreadable code and if anyone wants that there is another such tool readily available :-).